# DEL key giving wrong ASCII value

Tags: c, ascii

*EDIT: I am using Win10, vanilla CMD*

I checked a random [ascii table online](http://www.asciitable.com/) where it said :

> DEL key dec value: 127

, so I wrote a program to do just that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define EXKEY 127  //Important
#define CONKEY 32  //Not important


#define LAMBDA 3.2
#define VAL 0.5

double eq1(double a);

int main(){
    char key;
    double x;

    printf("Press SPACE to get the next iteration (DEL to exit)\n\n");
    getch();
    for (x=VAL;;){
        printf("%lf\n", eq1(x));
        x = eq1(x);

        //PROBLEM

        no: key = getch();
        if (key!= CONKEY){
            printf("%d, %c\n",key, key);
            goto no;
        }
        if (key == EXKEY){
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

double eq1(double a){
    /*
        Not important 
    */
    return LAMBDA*a*(1-a);
}
```

However, the output:

```
Press SPACE to get the next iteration (DEL to exit)

0.800000 //Pressed random key
83, S //[83,-32], These two results come when I press DEL
-32, α
83, S
-32, α
83, S
-32, α
83, S
115, s //I pressed s here
115, s
83, S //I pressed Shift+S here
83, S
83, S
83, S
83, S
```

I would be better off using TAB or BSpace but I am curious:

- How did -32 appear?
- Why 'S'?
- How come two values altogether?
- How to solve this if I ever again encounter this, not necessarily on my machine....

Comment: Need OS tag; it matters

Comment: 1. Why are you using `goto` 2. Think what is in the input buffer (new lines etc)

Comment: We also probably need to know what terminal you're using. The short answer is that that table shows the values of the BS (backspace) and DEL *characters*, not keys. Different terminals will do different things when you press those keys. If we know what system you're using, we might be able to give more information.

Comment: Modern keyboards don't have a key that sends the `DEL` character. If there's a Delete key on the main part of the keyboard, it actually sends `BS`. And the Delete key in the function keys sends the forward-delete Escape sequence.

Comment: I'd say it's a good bet that whatever system you're on, the keyboard key codes are not the same as the ASCII character codes.

Comment: FWIW, my delete key sends ESC[3~ (4 bytes)

Comment: BITD, to enter ASCII code 127, <Alt down><num pad 1><num pad 2><num pad 7><Alt up>.

Comment: "DEL to exit" is a really unusual thing to see in the 21st century. A safer, easier to test thing is "Continue? Y/n" with a default "Y".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That's a DOS/Windows-specific input method.

Comment: @EdHeal I used `goto` just to answer my textbook question.

Comment: `goto` is cursed. Stay away from it. You can go your whole career without using it. There's an exceedingly narrow set of circumstances under which it's the best choice, but those are so esoteric it's hard to even explain them.

Comment: You could (if allowed) use [GTK](http://gtk.org/) or [ncurses](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html)

Comment: I guess I'll have to use 'Q' instead of DEL.
@chux-ReinstateMonica that was very very helpful.

Comment: @tadman the "Curse of `goto`" is too cliche. I'm not even doing anything very serious. just purely educational. frankly, I hate `goto`.

Comment: It's not cliche. People hate it for a reason. It causes way more trouble than it's worth pretty much every time. This use here is completely unwarranted. You've used it like a really clunky version of `while ((key = getch()) != CONKEY)`. Using `goto` is like pulling out a gun. You better have a good reason, and you better be careful.

Comment: > FWIW, my delete key sends ESC[3~ (4 bytes)
I guess I have a lot to learn.

Comment: `while ((key = getch()) != CONKEY)`

Comment: again @tadman I'm just answering my textbook question. 

I should've just removed that bit but thought nothing mattered.

Comment: `getch()` is a pretty feeble function and I really wouldn't trust it with "multi-byte" keystrokes like DEL. There are OS-specific functions to get keypresses, like in Windows you'll receive a keypress event you can handle.

Comment: @tadman, your comment _`goto` is cursed_ is out of place.  Either argument on it, or don't give such comments, as you appear as if programming was some kind of witch stuff.  Computer science is a science, and not such.

Comment: @LuisColorado We're not writing CS papers all the time. There's room for more poetic descriptions. Writing `goto` laden code can lead to your code being effectively "cursed" since it can introduce unexpected behaviour. We're in an industry where we talk about "code smell", there's even tools named "curses", so getting upset about using "cursed" is really ridiculous.

Comment: @tadman, you write about goto as if it was some evil feature, and it is not..... it can be abused, and abuse can lead to misuse, but if it was evil, some standard release would have evicted it from the language.

Comment: @LuisColorado It can't be evicted for many reasons, least of which is C isn't about limiting programmer capabilities. It is, however, highly problematic when used casually, as this is a classic example of a goto that's completely pointless and only complicates what is actually simple code. Too many people jump to `goto` as the first solution and that's where you have problems. It should be your last resort.

Comment: ... a newbie would appreciate more the reasons you can argue about why `goto` is so evil, than your poetry and the kind of language you use to describe it.  He is learning, and has not yet completed about looping and constructs like `while` or `for`.  So it's my sensation that he has no other approach but to use `goto` (BTW it is the easiest to understand construct for looping)

Comment: @LuisColorado I'm not saying you can't use `goto`, you do you, but when advising programmers who are learning the best plan is to mark it as "off limits", something they'll be able to use when they're properly prepared for what it's intended for and what the consequences of misuse are.

Comment: @LuisColorado It's only "easy" if you're used to something like BASIC where jumping all over the place is a matter of course. Beginners should learn the fundamentals first, like how you can do pretty much anything without it.

Comment: nope, you are saying it's a nightmare, a curse.  in my humble opinion, this is worse.  You are scaring anybody that approaches to the language.

Comment: @LuisColorado, I'm just like Horace in Half Blood Prince "This is all hypothetical, all academic?"

Comment: @tadman, I sincerely don't like goto, I hate it. I don't (and won't) use it anymore. I already got ridiculed for my textbook author's mistake. I should've just rewritten the whole program following "The Meta". If this goes on, I'll retrograde from C to assembly, it's way better for me.

Comment: @LuisColorado I actually know looping constructs, since 1.5 years ago. I'm just way too used to python and perl and bash and suddenly wanted to revisit C from different perspective. Please, if you know anything important about keyboard inputs and keystroke return values, I'm all ears, just cut the chatter about `goto`, I won't use it on my behalf, PERIOD.

Comment: You should use OS-specific keyboard input functions, these give you way more detail than the kind of generic and generally crappy `getch()`.

Comment: @AbuBakarToha, from my point of view, you are using MS-DOS style programming, and PC environment.  `getch()` is not standard, and doesn't input caracters, but keyboard scan codes (scancodes are bytes representing key pressed/released and have nothing to do with ASCII)  Use `getchar()` for getting ascii characters. For some keys (function keys) each keystroke gives you several bytes in exchange.  But none represents an ascii char.